# ora 12505 Error listener refused to connect

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle10g, odbc

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
public class Stud
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            System.out.println("Driver Registered");
            Connection connection =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","bh","1234");
            System.out.println("Connection created");
            PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement("insert into Student(StudName,dob,math,phy,chem,agg) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            System.out.println("prepare stmt ");
            ps.setString(1,"name");

            ps.setString(2,"dob");
            ps.setInt(3,96);
            ps.setInt(4,96);
            ps.setInt(5,94);
            ps.setDouble(6,96);
            int a=ps.executeUpdate();
            ps.close();
            connection.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

### Error

```
java.sql.sql exception listner refused to connect with the following error
  ora 12505 the listner currently does not know of sid in give connectoin descriptor
  local host 1521
```

I'm using oracle 10 g and I have set the ojdbc14.jar in my class path.
I'm using Java 7 and my tnsname.ora also contain (PORT = 1521))
So I can't understand the given error.

Comment: `ora 12505 the listner currently does not know of sid in give connectoin descriptor`  Please copy/paste exception output wherever possible.  That has 2 spelling errors (listner -> listener, connectoin -> connection) and a suspiciously spelled word (give -> given).

Comment: Are you sure you have Oracle XE running on your local machine? Or on second thought, since you do not mention running the Express edition, are you sure the name of the Database you are connecting to is XE?

Answer (score 1):

You have your DB URL wrong. It should be:
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE  <- Notice slash instead of colon for a SID value (in your case "XE")

Answer (score 0):

From the [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/urls.htm#BEIDHCBA) your connection string should have this format:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:scott/tiger@//myhost:1521/myservicename
```